# How to set ReadOnlyField for all the fields on the sharepointList item in one go using rest

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I have to update SharePoint ListItem metadata fields and i can't since some fields are set ReadOnlyField to True by default. So to update them i first have to set ReadOnlyField to False individually for those fields and then i am able to update the item contents.

Is there a way i can update ReadOnlyField to False on ListItem level and not individual field level using rest?

I am trying to minimize my rest calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot update a ListItem field value when its definition is defined as read only by JSOM, CSOM even by the REST API.

However, to avoid multiple REST calls, you could make a REST batch request with 3 changesets *(Set readOnly field to false, update your listItem field value, Set readOnly field to true)* into a single API call.

References:

- [Make batch requests with the REST APIs (Microsoft Docs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis)
- [JS Sample (Andrew Connell)](https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/blob/master/SpRestBatchSample/Scripts/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lists web service to update read-only fields.
[Updating read-only fields with the Lists web service](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.sg/2010/04/updating-read-only-fields-with-lists.html)